# How to Set All Columns to NULL mysql pdo?

Tags: mysql

I need to set my columns to `NULL` to prevent the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field '' doesn't have a default value
```

Any idea on what query I need to run or if there are any examples?

Comment: What I meant is a Select * not one by one

Comment: Or you can alter your table and have them nullable by default, making no changes to your code.